# Extracting note content from OneNote using XmlDocument Class

Tags: vb.net, onenote

I am using vb.net and trying to extract the text out of a note in onenote (I'll settle for OneNote2010 or 2016.) The following code is capable of copying the titles of the books, and the names of the sections... to a text box (for testing), but not the actual content of the note. I know this is probably something VERY easy once you know how to do it once. But I for the life of me/google search can not figure out the magic command. (In Visual Basic).

Thank you for reading!

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim strNamespace As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote"
        Dim outputXML As String
        Dim onApplication As OneNote.Application = New OneNote.Application
        onApplication.GetHierarchy(Nothing, OneNote.HierarchyScope.hsSections, outputXML)

        Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(outputXML)
        Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("one", strNamespace)

        Dim Testa As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//one:Section[@name='TestNote']", nsmgr)

    TextBox1.Text = outputXML

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

To get page content, you will need to call onApplication.GetPageContent() with the appropriate pageID.

Look at the resulting XML. You will probably need to look for every one:T element, and concatenate. You will have to look for one:Bullet and one:Number for lists.

Here's the XSD that describes all the elements.
https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/63/17/0336.OneNoteApplication_2013_xsd.txt

Comment: Hi Jayongg,

     When I tried the GetPageContent route I get a 'getpagecontent' is not a member of 'OneNote'.  Maybe that's the route of my problem?

Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: Strange. are you using this API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I have : 
"Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Xml"
at the top...Sorry I'm still new at this.

Thanks

Comment: You should be importing a OneNote Interop assembly, not just an Office interop assembly.

Comment: Hi @jayongg, i've also imported the OneNote Interop assembly now. It's still giving the same error. I believe getpagecontent is only for VBA? Maybe it does not work for vb.net.

To recap I'm trying to programmatically find/save the name of a onenote page to a variable,then read the title of it saving that to a variable, and then read the content of that page to a variable.  The code I have so far only can copy the xml of the main book and assign it to a variable. Though I do see the pageID in the xml.

I have been trying for around 7 months now to figure this out. Any help is appreciated